# laravel 4 authentication always returns false

Tags: authentication, laravel, return

**Please help. My laravel 4 authentication always returns false.**

So far I have tried to make an authentication system. I followed several tutorials but none of them seem to work.

Here are some of my important files:

my auth.php

```
<?php

 return array(
    'driver'   => 'eloquent', 
    'model'    => 'User',  
    'table'    => 'users',
    'reminder' => array(
        'email'  => 'emails.auth.reminder',
        'table'  => 'password_reminders',
        'expire' => 60,
     ),
);
```

**In my controller I have this code to process the registration which works fine.**

```
public function store()
{
    // validate 
    $password=Input::get('password');
    $data = array(
    'email'           => Input::get('email'),
    'firstname'       => Input::get('firstname'),
    'lastname'        => Input::get('lastname'),
    'password'        => Hash::make($password)
    );              
    $rules = array(
        'firstname'       => 'required',
        'lastname'        => 'required',
        'email'           => 'unique:users',
        'password'        => 'required'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);        

    // process the registration
    if ($validator->fails()) 
    {
        Session::flash('message', 'This email is already registered, please choose    another one.');
        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } 
    else 
    {
        // store
        $user = new User;
        $user->firstname       = Input::get('firstname');
        $user->lastname        = Input::get('lastname');
        $user->email           = Input::get('email');
        $user->password        = Input::get('password');
        $user->save();

        // redirect
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created account! Please login to submit your ad.');
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}
```

**and here is the code to check my login process**

```
// process the login
public function doLogin()
{

    $email    = Input::get('email');
    $pass     = Input::get('password');
    $password = Hash::make($pass);

    $credentials = array(
       'email'    => $email,
       'password' => $password
    );

    if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) 
    {
         return 'success';
    }
    else 
    {
         return 'auth failed';
    }       

}
```

**And here is the code on my User model**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password');

/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}

/**
 * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return void
 */
public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

/**
 * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}

/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

When logging in, you do not have to hash the password. The `Auth::attempt()` method handles taking the input password, and checking it against the hashed password in the DB. So simply remove `$password = Hash::make($pass);` from your `doLogin()` method, and set your credentials array to

```
$credentials = array(
  'email' => $email,
  'password' => $pass
);
```

Now your auth should work fine.

Comment: yes I tried to use your suggestion,

$credentials = array(
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $pass
  ); 
  
  
  if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
         return 'success';
  }
  else {
         return 'auth failed';
  } 

but still I am receiving the same error. Btw,  My password has 255 characters limit. I also tried to delete and re-register my user but the error is still there.

Comment: It should.  A few things I can think of that would be causing this is your column in your database is too short, should be 60 characters long to store the full hashed password, the password you are using is incorrect or the user you are trying to login with simply does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

**To all laravel 4 developers who are facing the Auth::attempt() login failure with valid creditials!**

Solution:

- **In app/config/app.php change type:  'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 to 'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 and re-hash all passwords**
- In Model add method:

  ```
   public function setPasswordAttribute($pass) {

       $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($pass);
   }
  ```
- In UserController:

  //Create User or Register

  ```
     public function postCreate() {

      $input = Input::all();
      $user = new User;
      $user->username = Input::get('username');
      $user->email = Input::get('email');
      $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));    
      $user = User::create($input);
      return Redirect::action("Frontend\HomeController@index");
  ```

  }

  //Login or Sign in

  ```
  public function postSignin() {

      $userdata = array(
          'username' => Input::get('username'),
          'password' => Input::get('password')
      );

      if (Auth::attempt($userdata, true)) {
           Session::put('username', Auth::user()->username);
           return Redirect::action("Frontend\HomeController@index");
      } else {
           return Redirect::action("Frontend\UserController@getLogin")
                  ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
                  ->withInput();
  }
  ```

Hope i have helped someone out there

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the default driver in app/auth.php from eloquent to database . It work for me.